# Can I pass something that responds to call to RSpec's change matcher?

Tags: ruby, rspec, duck-typing

I've got code like

```
it 'transfers the account balance to the recipient' do
  expect(&transaction_creator.method(:call)).to change(account, :balance_cents).by(54_321_01)
end
```

which works, but it feels wrong. I was under the impression that something that responds to `call` ought to be able to act like a proc or a lambda, because of Ruby's duck-typing. However, if I do `expect(&transaction_creator)` I get

```
wrong argument type TransactionCreator (expected Proc)
```

and if I do `expect(transaction_creator)`, I get

```
expected #balance_cents to have changed by 5432101, but was not given a block
```

Is there any way of simplifying `&transaction_creator.method(:call)`?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you may need to define `to_proc` for `TransactionCreator` in order to make `expect(&transaction_creator)` work. After all `&:foo` calls `Symbol#to_proc` and `&transaction_creator.method(:call)` calls `Method#to_proc`.

```
class Foo ; end
Foo.new
[].map(&foo)
TypeError: wrong argument type Foo (expected Proc)

class Foo ; def to_proc ; -> {} ; end ; end
[].map(&foo)
=> []
```

Also if you relied on duck-typing, you should leave off the `&` which forces conversion to a `Proc`.